# Can you use only the first summation term of cost function for typical logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning

I have recently come across a [Matlab implementation](https://github.com/hushell/drnn/tree/master/PGM/model/lr) that appears to be using only the first term (i.e. in itself a product) of the typical logistic regression cost function. 
[image]

```
f = - full(mean(sum(Y.*log(Yr))));
f = f + 0.5*lambda*sum(W(:).^2);
```

When I create a two class simple dataset and adjust the cost function to its traditional form I still get separation between classes albeit the vector of parameters are slightly different (for a fixed lambda regularizer in both cases).

[image]

```
f = - full(mean(sum(Y.*log(Yr) + (1-Y).*log(1-Yr))));
f = f + 0.5*lambda*sum(W(:).^2);
```

For better visualization see the following plot
[image: Orange due to simpler, blue due to full cost]

Once the cost function is set, the parameters are learned using limited-memory BFGS. Gradient functions remain the same (i.e. derived from the correct classical cost function).
[image]

Naturally, my question is: Has this choice been deliberate ? Is the first objective function sufficient ? Or is it just an obvious inconsistency.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually I have realized where the misunderstanding came from. In fact the implementation aforementioned specifies a cost for the general case, namely the multinational logistic regression. Therefore the implementation is deliberate and correct.

See the screenshot below.

[image]